# Which jars are blacklisted in Java 8 JRE release?

Tags: java, java-8, jar, blacklist, jar-signing

I am using Java 8, and facing problems while downloading SecurityPack.jar. In some posts I found that this jar has been blacklisted. So, I wanted to know where will I find list of jars which are blacklisted for my current version of JRE release ?

A blacklist is a list of signed jars that contain serious security vulnerabilities that can be exploited by untrusted applets or applications. A system-wide blacklist will be distributed with each JRE release. Java Plugin and Web Start will consult this blacklist and refuse to load any class or resource contained in a jar file that's on the blacklist. By default, blacklist checking is enabled.

Comment: Are you *downloading* a jar, as you said at the beginning, or do you try to run an applet or web start application? These are two entirely different things.

Comment: Following link could help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/blacklistfeature.html

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the blacklist, find your Java SE binary location. In that folder then go to `lib/security`, then delete all text in `blacklist`, or if you want to find the blacklisted jar, use a `base64`-ed `sha-256-digest` on the jar file you want to check. If that base64-ed sha256 digest is in the `blacklist` file, it is blacklisted.